# does android drop the cellular connection when there is a wifi connection?

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to iterate through the network interfaces on android:

```
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                 Log.e("get ip: ", inetAddress.getHostAddress());

            }
        }
    }
```

but if I am connected to a wifi network I only get the wifi IP, where I would expect both the wifi and cellular ip (the phone is on the cell network and got a ip, then I turn on the wifi and suddenly it only reuturns the wifi ip).

So do anyone know what happens? If I use similar code on a iphone I get both cellular and wifi IP.

Comment: As an Android phone user, I have to say, YES, Android will drop mobile data connection when WiFi is connected (And the data connection Icon will disappear). This should be a protection to reduce mobile data usage by the System.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You will notice it turns on briefly when you fire up Android Market so that the Market can check your network headers in order to determine which country you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, android only keeps one of wifi or cellular connected at a time.  It looks like ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost will allow you to force connections over a particular transport, but personally I've never tried it.